# Read file from windows directory

Tags: java, xml, stream

I tried reading xml from windows path `D:/xml/xmlfile.xml`

On my webpage there is a browse button. I select file and click submit. I comes to my controller and there is code to read this file.

`fileToRead` variable has a value = file name. Not full directory path.

```
InputStream ips = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileToRead);
InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
          BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
          String line;
          while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
              System.out.println(line);
          }
```

This did not read file. Another technique also did not work and I got `File not found exception`

```
InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Take a moment to think about this.  Would you really like to have your harddisk exposed to every web form that had an <file> tag?  This is not how this process works.  The browser sends the file as multi-part stream. You could take a look at [RFC1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) and [RFC2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) or simply use something like [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

Comment: So it means I cannot read file using this method. I need to upload file to server and then read it. Am I correct?

Comment: Basically, yes. But, depending on the approach you take/API you use, it may be capable of returning a InputStream as part of the upload process for you

Comment: But I am getting null InputStream and File not found exception in both of above mentioned methods respectively.

Comment: The file you are looking for DOES NOT EXIST within the context of your server, it has not been uploaded to you.  That is the responsibility of the multi-part stream.  You need to read it, save or process the content that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File should be on server if you want to just give file name or relative path. You have to upload file to server then read. Else you have to give full path to read file from windows directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into this site. There is working code for your  problem.

http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/eclipse-file-upload-servlet-with-apache-common-file-upload